# Canvas Object flickering

Tags: javascript, object, canvas, html5-canvas

I have eyesore flickering in my canvas animation. I have no idea what causes the flicker and the Google is not offering help on the transition global element I added to my text. On separate canvases, they work fine. It's only when I add them to the main code do I run into the flicker.

```
    var canvas,
        context,
        ox = 60,
        oy = 60,
        ux = Math.random(),
        uy = Math.random();
    var drops = [];
    var squares = [];
    var clouds = [];
    var text, step = 190, steps = 255;
            delay = 180;
    var rgbstep = 120;


    function Drop(x,y,color){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.color = color;
        this.dy = Math.random();
    }


    function Square(x,y,w,color){
        this.sx = x;
        this.sy = y;
        this.sw = w;
        this.color = color;
        this.qy = Math.random();
    }







    function init(){
        canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        //alert("Hello!\nClick on the screen for rain drops!");
        window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);
        window.addEventListener('orientationchange', resizeCanvas, false);
        resizeCanvas()
        Textfadeup(); 
        canvas.onclick = function(event){
            handleClick(event.clientX, event.clientY);
        };
        setInterval(handleClick,50);
        setInterval(draw, 1);





    }



      addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 32)
          document.body.style.background = "yellow";


      });
      addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 32)
          document.body.style.background = "";
    });




    function handleClick(x,y,w){
        var found = false;
        for(var i = 0; i<drops.length; i++){
            d = Math.sqrt((drops[i].x-x)*(drops[i].x-x) + (drops[i].y-y)*(drops[i].y-y));
            if(d<=5){
                drops.splice(i,1);
                found = true;
            }
        }

        fillBackgroundColor();
        if(!found){
        var colors = ["#000080", "#add8e6", "blue"];
        var color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
            drops.push(new Drop(x,y,color));
            squares.push(new Square(x,y,w,color));

        }

                for(var i = 0; i<drops.length; i++){
            drawDrop(drops[i]);
        }
                for(var i = 0; i<squares.length; i++){
            drawSquare(squares[i]);
        }

    }







    function Textfadeup() {
                rgbstep++;
                //context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                context.fillStyle = "rgb(" + rgbstep + "," + rgbstep + "," + rgbstep + ")"
                context.fillText("Drip, drip, drop, little April shower...", 500, canvas.height);
                context.font= "40px Arial";
                if (rgbstep < 255)
                    var t = setTimeout('Textfadeup()', 10);
                if (rgbstep == 255) {
                    Textfadedown();
                }
    }

    function Textfadedown() {
             rgbstep=rgbstep-1;
               // context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                context.fillStyle = "rgb(" + rgbstep + "," + rgbstep + "," + rgbstep + ")"
                context.fillText("Drip, drip, drop, little April shower...", 500, canvas.height);
                context.font= "40px Arial";
                if (rgbstep > 30)
                    var t = setTimeout('Textfadedown()', 10);
                if (rgbstep == 30) {
                    Textfadeup();
                }
            }   






     /* function drawDrop(drop){
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(drop.x,drop.y);
        context.lineTo(drop.x+10,drop.y+25);
        context.lineTo(drop.x+13,drop.y+32);
        context.lineTo(drop.x+46,drop.y+50);
        context.lineTo(drop.x+72,drop.y+51);
        context.lineTo(drop.x+81,drop.y+43);
        context.lineTo(drop.x+104,drop.y+52);
        context.lineTo(drop.x+111,drop.y+46);
        context.lineTo(drop.x+83,drop.y+40);
        context.lineTo(drop.x+75,drop.y+20);
        context.lineTo(drop.x+57,drop.y+8);
        context.closePath();
        context.fillStyle = 'orange';
        context.fill();
        if (drop.y + drop.dy > canvas.height || drop.y + drop.dy < 0)
            drop.dy != -drop.dy;
        drop.y += drop.dy;
    };



    function drawDrop(drop){
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(drop.x,drop.y);
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(drop.x,drop.y);
        context.lineTo(drop.x+24,drop.y);
        context.lineTo(drop.x-2,drop.y+25);
        context.lineTo(drop.x+17,drop.y+25);
        context.lineTo(drop.x-18,drop.y+53);
        context.lineTo(drop.x-3,drop.y+54);
        context.lineTo(drop.x-47,drop.y+77);
        context.lineTo(drop.x-31,drop.y+59);
        context.lineTo(drop.x-40,drop.y+59);
        context.moveTo(drop.x-40,drop.y+59);
        context.moveTo(drop.x-14,drop.y+33);
        context.lineTo(drop.x-30,drop.y+32);
        context.closePath();
        context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
        context.fill();
        if (drop.y + drop.dy > canvas.height || drop.y + drop.dy < 0)
            drop.dy != -drop.dy;
        drop.y += drop.dy;
    };*/



    function drawDrop(drop){
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(drop.x, drop.y, 5, 0, Math.PI);
        context.fillStyle = drop.color;
        context.moveTo(drop.x - 5, drop.y);
        context.lineTo(drop.x, drop.y - 7);
        context.lineTo(drop.x + 5, drop.y);
        context.closePath();
        context.fill();
        if (drop.y + drop.dy > canvas.height || drop.y + drop.dy < 0)
            drop.dy != -drop.dy;
        drop.y += drop.dy;
    };


    function drawSquare(square){
        var sw = Math.floor(4);
        var sx = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
        var sy = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height);
        context.beginPath();
        context.rect(sx, sy, sw, sw); 
        context.fillStyle = '#add8e6';
        context.fill();

    };


    function drawCloud(ox,oy) {
             context.beginPath();
             context.moveTo(ox,oy);
             context.bezierCurveTo(ox-40, oy+20, ox-40, oy+70, ox+60, oy+70);
             context.bezierCurveTo(ox+80, oy+100, ox+150, oy+100, ox+170, oy+70);
             context.bezierCurveTo(ox+250, oy+70, ox+250, oy+50, ox+220, oy+20);
             context.bezierCurveTo(ox+260, oy-40, ox+200, oy-50, ox+170, oy-30);
             context.bezierCurveTo(ox+150, oy-75, ox+80, oy-10, ox+170, oy+5);
             context.bezierCurveTo(ox+30, oy-75, ox-20, oy-60, ox, oy);
             context.closePath();
             context.fillStyle = 'white';
             context.fill();

    };

    function fillBackgroundColor(){
        context.fillStyle = 'gray';
        context.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    }
    function resizeCanvas(){
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 20;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 20;
        for(var i = 0; i<drops.length; i++){
            drawDrop(drops[i]);
        }
         for(var i = 0; i<squares.length; i++){
            drawSquare(squares[i]);
        }

    }

    function draw() {
      drawCloud(ox, oy, 500);
      if (ox + ux > canvas.width || ox + ux < 0)
        ux = -ux;   
        if (oy + uy > canvas.height || oy + uy < 0)
        uy = -uy;
      ox += ux;
     }





    function degreesToRadians(degrees) {
            return (degrees * Math.PI)/180;
        }
    window.onload = init;

    </script>
    <body>
    <canvas id='canvas' width=500 height=500></canvas>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use setInterval to render to the canvas. You have set the time to 10 which is quicker than the screen refresh rate. There is no easy fix to your code as it's a little convoluted.

What you need to do is set up a main loop. From that function you do everything you need to do per animation frame. At the end of that function you use `window.requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop)` to request the next frame. It syncs the animation with the display refresh rate and stops the flicker.

Example

```
function mainLoop(){
   drawCloud();  // draw your cloud
   // other stuff did not get a chance to see what else you did.
   // request the next animation frame that should occur in 1/60th of a second.
   requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
```

To start it all call `mainLoop` from the `init` function

```
mainLoop(); // starts it all happening
```

You should NEVER use setInterval for anything but very short simple functions or long time periods. It caused your jsFiddle to crash the tab each time I looked.

Comment: Alright. So why is it, even though I'm telling the setInterval command to talk to the handleClick function, it ends up affecting the text and cloud shape?

Comment: You should gather all the render calls into the one call. As you had it the `handleClick` function was interfering with the `cloud function` especially as they both had differing timing. It is best to group all the logic together and all the rendering together. The rendering should be as simple as possible and the logic handles all the complex interactions.